# Java 64 Bit on Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, java, 64-bit

I switch the Kernel of my Raspbi 4 to 64 Bit by changing the `/boot/config.txt` adding `arm_64bit=1`.

After a reboot `uname -a` shows `Linux raspberrypi 5.4.72-v8+ #1358 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 26 17:29:14 GMT 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

So it looks like the 64 Bit kernel is running.

When installing JRE 11 by `sudo apt install default-jre` it looks like it still uses the 32 Bit version.

So is the PI really running in 64 Bit know?

How can I install a 64 Bit JRE 11?

Comment: Did you use the 64bit version of Raspberry Pi OS or have you just ended up with the OS reporting 64bit with a 32bit user space?

Comment: the latter one.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues as you, I've posted another question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/122346/installing-x64-java-on-the-model-4). It would be great if you could let me know if you've made progress on this

Answer (score 1):

In Debian and derivatives, the default system architecture is not defined by the kernel, but by the architecture of your `dpkg` package:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -l | grep dpkg
ii  dpkg                                   1.19.7                               
armhf        Debian package management system
```

Unless you switch `dpkg` to `arm64`, any package installation command where the architecture is not specified will assume `armhf`.

You could try to install `arm64` version of Java with

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt update
apt install default-jre:arm64
```

Update: it seems that the actual (at the time of this edit) version of 64-bit Pi OS is getting packages from `http://deb.debian.org/debian`. Beware that on a 32-bit Pi OS, adding Debian repo as a source and doing an upgrade is known to ruin the system (at least it was the case last time I tried).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If you add arm64 there are error messages that arm64 is not supported by some repositories.

Comment: @Nabor Perhapsh you should add `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/multiarch/ <your_distro> main contrib non-free` to your `sources.list` The key part is **multiarch**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, even though I've added the architecture, updated the sources.list and ran a ```sudo apt update```. Running ```sudo apt info default-jre:arm64``` returns, ```N: Unable to locate package default-jre:aarch64
N: Unable to locate package default-jre:aarch64
E: No packages found```

Comment: @SidS That would mean there is no 64-bit Java package for your distribution (Raspbian I assume?). There certainly is one for Debian (https://packages.debian.org/buster/openjdk-11-jre) and I bet there is one for Ubuntu too. I think many 64-bit users use Ubuntu, you could try that. Or wait until it gets ported to Raspbian.

Comment: I think it's because I initially installed the 32-bit Raspbian OS then enabled the 64-bit kernel. If I had installed the 64-bit OS instead, I may have been able to avoid this issue. I am reflashing the RPi drive with the 64-bit, let's see if that help

Comment: @SidS Are you sure there is such a thing as 64-bit Raspbian? I see nothing by that name in https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/, there's only a 32-bit version. That's the whole point: unlike Ubuntu, "64-bit Raspbian" is actually a 32-bit Raspbian with a 64-bit kernel and a few 64-bit packages. The core of the system is still 32-bit.

Comment: I think there is, it can be found [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/), It's not on the main website as it's in beta. I'll try this out first, if it doesn't work then I might switch to Ubuntu

Comment: @SidS Then it might do the trick, though I wouldn't bet on it. I see no JRE package in http://archive.raspbian.org/multiarch/pool/main/j/. Please let me know how your experiment goes. Perhaps post an answer here if you get it working.

Comment: I've installed and set up the 64-bit Raspbian and after running ```sudo apt update``` and ```sudo apt install default-jdk``` it installs the 64-bit JavaJDK. ```openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2, mixed mode)```. So I guess it seems to work

Comment: The reason why I'm a bit hesitant to switch to Ubuntu is because I've heard that its quite heavy and takes up more hardware resources than Raspbian - but if I do run into any issues in the future with this beta 64-bit Raspbian install, I'm switching to Ubuntu

Comment: @SidS Could you please check what's inside your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I've pasted the contents of that file to a Pastebin, here's the [link](https://pastebin.com/1wvsscg3)