# Installing ARM64 Java On The Model 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, debian, java, 64-bit

I am trying to install the ARM64 version of Java on my Raspberry Pi model 4.

I have already added `arm_64bit=1` to the `/boot/config.txt` file and running `uname -a` returns `Linux pi4 5.10.17-v8+ #1403 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 22 11:37:54 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux`. This shows that I am running the 64-bit kernel.

Installing JRE 11 with `sudo apt install default-jre` seems to be installing the 32-bit version of Java 11.

I first thought that `apt` was installing the 32-bit version and I had to change it to the ARM64 architecture so I followed [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/java-64-bit-on-pi-4) answer from another question. This only lead to more errors when I went to `sudo apt update` and didn't install the 64-bit version.

So the next thing I tried was dowloaded an `aarch64` version of OpenJDK11. I did the following (slightly modified from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1509333)):

```
cd /home/pi/
wget https://cdn.azul.com/zulu-embedded/bin/zulu11.35.36-ca-jdk11.0.5-linux_aarch64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf zulu*tar.gz
mv zulu11.35.36-ca-jdk11.0.5-linux_aarch64 java-11-zulu-aarch64
mv java-11-zulu-aarch64 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-zulu-aarch64
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-zulu-aarch64/java 1091
```

After I had set `update-alternatives` with the newly installed Java:

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-zulu-aarch64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Running `java -version` outputs this:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get an installation of ARM64 Java JDK on my Raspberry Pi Model 4?

Could it be a possibility that I needed to have flashed the 64-bit Raspbian Lite OS from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/), rather than flashing the 32-bit then setting `arm_64bit=1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be a possibility that I needed to have flashed the x64
> Raspbian Lite OS from here, rather than flashing the x32 then setting
> arm_64bit=1?

Looks like it.  The flag just means run the kernel in 64-bit mode.  All the applications and libraries will still be 32-bit.

Comment: I see, is there a way to change ```apt``` to install ARM64 based programs, or do I need to make lower-level modifications to achieve this? If I need to make lower-level modifications, then I think it'll be easier to just reinstall the OS making sure I use the 64-bit version

Comment: you need to install the beta 64bit OS - https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

Comment: The ```raspios_lite_arm64``` from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/) should be fine too right? I was thinking of going with the lite version as I'm going to be running it headless

Comment: Just installed the ```raspios_lite_arm64``` image on the Pi, and after updating then running ```sudo apt install default-jdk```, the 64-bit JDK installs successfully. I guess this answers my question - settings the ```arm_64bit``` flag isn't enough, you have to install the actual 64-bit OS